# logback isn't creating log file in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logback

I added logback to my spring mvc 4 project. its working in console but doesn't create log file and write logs into it.

my dependencies are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and my logback.xml configuration in /classes path is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- log INFO or higher messages to the console -->
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- log everything to a rolling file -->
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/files/log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <!-- use AsyncAppender for lower latencies -->
    <appender name="async" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <!--<appender-ref ref="console"/>-->
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </appender>


    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**EDIT**

i enable debugiing with debug=true and delete first forward slash but result like following and logback can not write in file

```
 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file /IdeaProjects/spring/target/spring-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [console]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [file]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
|-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@501115326 - No compression will be used
|-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@501115326 - Will use the pattern logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
|-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.
|-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
|-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to 
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file] - Active log file name: files/log
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file] - File property is set to [files/log]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [async]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [file] to ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[async]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[async] - Attaching appender named [file] to AsyncAppender.
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[async] - Setting discardingThreshold to 51
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [console] to Logger[ROOT]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [file] to Logger[ROOT]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@73ae94ae - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContainerInitializer@16c752bf - Adding an instance of  class ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContextListener to the current web-app
INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Aug 14 20:34:04 IRDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]
```

and logback can not write in file

Comment: Are you sure you need the first forward-slash here: `/files/log`? Adding debug option `<configuration debug="true">` might reveal something.

Comment: I just checked a configuration I've used successfully and my path begins with a leading `./`, so try `./files/log` and make sure the `files` and `log` directories exist (e.g. with `mkdir -p files/log`).

Comment: where i create files/log directory? @David Conrad

Comment: Uh, under the directory you run it from, where want it to put the log files? Although, come to think of it, I don't think I had to the directory myself. I think it will create it.

Comment: i want put log files in directory of spring application that run with tomcat. @David Conrad